Deploying a web app on vercel, back-end is not started
I have a nextjs/typescript webapp project that I'm hosting in vercel, with the free tier. To start my project, I do npm run dev in the app folder, which starts the front end. Then, in another terminal, I navigate to the back-end folder and do a npm start. My file structure looks something like this
app
|-back-end
|---back-end stuff
|-front-end stuff

Now the problem with Vercel is that the deployment only does npm run start (which starts the front end), so the back end functions don't work. How can I also deploy the back end too, or is that not possible with the free tier?

I have a Nextjs fullstack application I've been working on for the past few months that I'm also deploying to Vercel. Backend uses Postgres with a Prisma ORM. My (very) simplified file structure goes something like this:
root
|-app (folder)
|-prisma (folder)
|-package.json

I only need one terminal to turn my frontend and backend on. Here are my scripts in my package.json file:
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "prisma generate && next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },

I'd also go to your project's settings page on the Vercel website and check General -> Build & Development Settings and make sure everything looks good. There are probably tutorials on Vercel too for deployment as well. Hope this helps.
Edit: I also forgot to mention that I have a connected git repository which auto deploys to Vercel when I use git push origin main. That is in Settings -> General -> Git on the Vercel website.
